# How to check wether the SD card is corrupted on Android

Tags: java, android

Here is the scenario:

I'm saving data from network to local storage. And there are occasions that the SD card is partially corrupted.

There are several methods that I could come out with:

**IOException**

Assuming an IOException will be thrown when `write` or `flush` on corrupted blocks. This is not tested yet since I don't have a corrupted SD card. So this one is a hypothesis.

**Comparing the size**

After every `flush` I compare the size of written buffer with actual file. I think is more practical despite its inelegance.

**Checksum**

This method is not reliable because there're two factors that would cause a corrupted file: error on network or SD card. So I can't point out which is the real cause.

Any suggestion will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**Update**:

Sorry for the obscure. I read data from `HttpEntity.getContent()` write to a `RandomAccessFile`. The underlying protocol of `HttpEntity.getContent()` is TCP.

Comment: I don't think there is some "hard" indicator of corruption.  Applications generally don't care to know things that specific.  That said, if there is a problem writing to disk or any reason at all, it's nice to let the user know.  Corrupt media typically results in lots of things failing, not just one thing failing, so the user likely knows there is something wrong with the device in the event of media failure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the sd cards state

```
Boolean Accessable = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(Accessable)
{
  // Sd card is accessable, write data
}
else
{
 // probably corrupted or removed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TCP, networking errors will be taken care of. TCP protocol does retransmit/abort transparent to the app developer. You will get IOException if it can't receive the data correctly. If you are not using TCP, then you can build the logic to have some validation done by using checksums. 
Once the networking layer completes its error checking, then you can have your SD card error logic.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask about TCP.

Comment: OP mentions reading of data from the network. TCP is one of the most common protocols that is used to read data from the network. I have asked for clarification about that part. Hopefully the OP will clarify that part.